# Update of Docker intermediate images

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

Let's suppose I build a MyApp Docker based on Tomcat 8 (Dockerfile FROM tomcat:8) from Docker Hub.
The Tomcat 8 Docker is itself based on Java 7, which currently is 7.0.65.
Eventually, the Java 7 Docker (java:7 tag) gets updated to version 7.0.100 for example.

What happens if I re-build again my MyApp on a new machine where the Docker repository is empty? Does it gets the new Java 7 (7.0.100) or it stays with the original (7.0.65).

Answer (score 0):

It will pull the latest tomcat:8 from Docker Hub, so it'll be the new Java7.

If you want a specific version of java, take the the Tomcat dockerfile and modify its `FROM`, then use it with your app.

Links to the Tomcat dockerfiles can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've just used Tomcat and Java as well known examples. My case involves custom application.